# Problems with specific unix commands while using Jsch (Exec) on Android

Tags: android, linux, shell, exec, jsch

Hello i was doing a couple of days and research and some problem analysis, but i have no clue how to solve my Problem right now.

Maybe someone can help....

I am using Jsch for Android devices to access my raspberry pi in order to set some specific commands.

I began with Jsch shell command and everything worked fine besides the fact that i was never able to close a connection due to an infinite loop.

I tried to switch to Exec especially because i just want to send a couple of commands and do not really need to nood what happens on the shell.

Anyways... here is my code:
The intention is to send a cec sleep signal to my tv...

```
 public c_jsch(String userName, String password,
                  String connectionIP, String knownHostsFileName)
{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    System.out.println("com.jcraft.jsch BBÄÄÄHHMM");
    try
    {
        Session session = jsch.getSession("pi", "192.168.188.23", 22);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword("raspberry");
        session.connect();

        String command = "/home/pi/.xbmc-current/xbmc-bin/bin/cec-client -s -d 1";
        String command2 = "tx 10 36 \r \n";

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand(command);

        channel.setInputStream(null);

        channel.connect();
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        //NOT YET USEFUL
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();

        System.out.println("com.jcraft.jsch Unix system connected...");

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            while (in.available() > 0)
            {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0){
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print("com.jcraft.jsch Feedback: " + new String(tmp, 0, i));
                // NOT WORKING
                out.write(command2.getBytes());
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("com.jcraft.jsch Command flushed");
            }
            if (channel.isClosed())
            {
                System.out.println("com.jcraft.jsch exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
            }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("com.jcraft.jsch exit-status: DONE");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("com.jcraft.jsch exit-status: " +  e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Trying this code throws no error messages but a disappointing exit status-message: 127.
This means command not found.... so i assume there is a big difference between shell and exec commands ... with shell i works like a charm on ssh.

I hope you can help me.

:::Update, as i was first working with Pipes | that are not sufficient for exec and had to add Outputstream in order to send commands after connected to the channel i was able to realise sending commands to my Tv... thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with your setup, but your problem may be that "echo 'tx 10 36' | cec-client -s -d 1" requires a `shell` to interpret the pipe character, while an "exec" command typically invokes a process directly without a shell as an intermediary.  Perhaps you can figure out a way to invoke cec-client and push data into its stdin.  Or perhaps you can build a customized cec-client which does this without input, or takes a string as a command line argument.

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback i do not want to add any code to the raspberry but want to keep it as it is inkl. the XBMC setup running on it to be able to perform the same task n multiple devices. ... But the Pipe is a good hint maybe i can figure out away to get along this

Comment: See if you can launch a bare cec-client process and use something like channel.getOutputStream to write the string data into that process, instead of the echo and pipe.

Comment: Even if i do not use pipe and just the cec command i receive an 127 message

Comment: Perhaps there is a path issue?  What if you find the full path of the cec command and use that?

Comment: I was able to get the first part the cec command running, but as he command waits for input i do not come further... i tried this three lines:

OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
out.write("tx 10 36".getBytes());
out.flush();

Comment: Try sending a newline.  And maybe then close the stream.

Comment: i tried channel.setCommand(command2); after i oppened the channel... but this did not work. just pretended second command did not exist --- i also made an update to the code above ... to give a short headsup on my status here.

Comment: Not sure why you would do that.  I would try one command "cec-client -s -d 1" and then push "tx 10 36\n" (or whatever you have to do to encode a newline) into the OutputStream, and then perhaps close the stream.  If you have a hexdump on that platform you could try using that as a test target process instead of cec-client and making sure that the newline is getting through.

Comment: Oh, and don't put the "echo" in the string you write.  echo is a program which you would no longer be using, not part of the data you want to push into the cec-client process

Comment: Sorry it was far to late yesterday for me ..... German time .*
I updated my code above and added /r /n to the string that i was going to flush. this was actually the open issue. 
Thanks again for you support on this.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code above and added /r /n to the string that i was going to flush. this was actually the open issue. – DerKai